# What is the meaning of the following sequence of words: "adj or pp+as+pronoun+verb"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

What is the meaning of the following sequence of words: "adj or pp+as+pronoun+verb"?

Example:

> It is climate that largely determines the type of agriculture that may be carried out in a particular area, **governed as that is** by the overall prevailing temperatures, and the variations that may take place from year to year and over a longer term. [Source](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=Z2fODQAAQBAJ&lpg=PP1&pg=PP1&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false)

I simply couldn't find this structure in any English Usage Guide.

Comment: It would be impossible to categorise every possible combination of phrase structures in a clause. Your example happens to be a supplementary non-finite passive clause in which "that" is a pro-form referring (presumably) to the NP "agriculture that may be carried out in a particular area".

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of what [Huddleston & Pullum (2002)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Cambridge_Grammar_of_the_English_Language) call *preposing in PP structure* (pp. 633-634). In this case, the word "governed" has been removed from its subordinate clause and placed before the "as." Here "as" just means "because"; if we undo the preposing and make that replacement, the meaning becomes clear:

> It is climate that largely determines the type of agriculture that may be carried out in a particular area, **since that (i.e., agriculture) is governed** by the overall prevailing temperatures, and the variations that may take place from year to year and over a longer term.

Comment: Yes. / It would be good to include the first sentence of the paragraph headed 'Restriction to _though_ and _as_, and at least one of H & P's examples.